# Who took the cookie from the AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, session, cookies

When I call a URL via AJAX, which cookies does it read? Same goes for sessions.

Who actually runs the thread? Is it my default system browser, current one, some other entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be confusing, since it all happens 'behind the scenes'. I found that, like any other Javascript, the browser loading the page is the one to run the AJAX code. Moreover - the same instance of the browser, meaning sessions can be used as well.

---

I've run a bit of code to come to this conclusion. The following examples are in classic ASP.

Firstly, I have one file which writes these variables:

```
Response.Cookies("testing") = "One, Two, Three"
Session("testing") = "Forty One, Forty Two, Forty Three"
```

Next, one file to read them (and display result):

```
Cookie is: 
<%
Response.Write Request.Cookies("testing")
%>
<br>
Session is:
<%
Response.Write Session("testing")
%>
```

At last, one file to AJAXly call them:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Different browsers initiate ajax differently
try {var oXH = eval("new Active"+"X"+"Object('MSXML2.XMLHTTP')");}
catch(e) {var oXH = new XMLHttpRequest();}

//Call page that reads the cookie
oXH.open("GET","/testCookie.asp",true);
oXH.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if ((oXH.readyState != 4)||(oXH.status != 200))
        return true;
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = oXH.responseText;
    }
};
oXH.send(null);
</script>
```

Running the first file on one browser and the last on a few, the first one shows:

```
Cookie is: One, Two, Three
Session is: Forty One, Forty Two, Forty Three
```

The rest display:

```
Cookie is:
Session is:
```

So there you have it :)